# Complete set of $L_2[a,b]$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

How can we prove that $\{\frac{e^{int}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\}\bigg|_{n\in Z}$ is a complete set?
I saw a proof which uses first that this is a complete set in in $C([-\pi,\pi]_0)$ (i.e, the continuous periodical functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$), by Stone Weirstrass. Why can't we imply Stone Weirstrass directly on $C[a,b]$?

Comment: Because it doesnt seperate the points of that space in general.

Comment: Can I have an example please?

Comment: The given set of functions do not separate points of $[-\pi,\pi]$ because they're all periodic with period $2\pi$. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: I think i understand, thanks.